# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

I'm trying to find a parental control for Ubuntu that turns adult site words into *. I have tried webcontentcontrol (doesn't even ask me to set a password), mobicip (doesn't even get listed in package names). My family can see my adult bookmark names and that's really embarrassing.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol  
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo pkill webcontentcontrol  
sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol
```

but still can't uninstall it.

Googling for that error message resulted in a solution that is first said dangerous, later said wrong.

After `sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol`, I always get the error message "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".

What should I do?

UPDATE:

the dpkg configure error message:

```
deltrem@deltrem-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg-configure -a
sudo: dpkg-configure: command not found
```

the adult bookmarks and private browsing:

private browsing is for adult history, not adult bookmarks

UPDATE:

the full webcontentcontrol removal error message, instead of in brazilian portuguese, in english now

```
deltrem@deltrem-desktop:~$ LANG=C sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol
[sudo] password for deltrem: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gambas2-gb-form kdelibs4c2a clamav clamav-freshclam kdelibs-data aggregate
  liblualib50 clamav-base gambas2-gb-form-dialog libclamav6 gambas2-runtime
  gambas2-gb-qt libavahi-qt3-1 gambas2-gb-qt-kde-html python-sqlite
  gambas2-gb-qt-kde python-hachoir-regex libtommath0 libqt3-mt liblua50
  gambas2-gb-gtk gambas2-gb-gui python-gtop gambas2-gb-settings
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  webcontentcontrol
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1929kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 160290 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing webcontentcontrol ...
===>prerm:remove
prerm remove|deconfigure called
Unconfiguring dansguardian+firehol+tinyproxy
FireHol is stopped
TinyProxy is stopped
DansGuardian is stopped
/var/lib/dpkg/info/webcontentcontrol.prerm: line 50: /etc/init.d/firehol: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing webcontentcontrol (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
===>postinst:abort-remove
Errors were encountered while processing:
 webcontentcontrol
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

in /var/lib/dpkg/info/webcontentcontrol.list is

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/README_selfcontrol.txt
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/README
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/COPYING.gz
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/copyright
/usr/share/doc/webcontentcontrol/TODO
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/webcontentcontrol
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/webcontentcontrol.png
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/webcontentcontrol.1.gz
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/CustomApps.conf
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/reference
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/reference/reference.tar.gz
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs/Minimal.tcs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs/Default.tcs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs/Strict.tcs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs/Moderate.tcs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/preset_configs/AdBlocker.tcs
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/autosetports.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/install.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/sizeof_package.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/list_upgradable_packages.pl
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/cron_reminder.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/upgrade_one_by_one_2.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/list_installed_packages_by_size.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/remindme.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other2/upgrade_one_by_one.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/sudoers.locked.template
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_ports_nogui.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/disable_script.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/apply_all_settings.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedextension.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/sudoers.unlocked
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedphrase.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/ifupdown_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/common_functions.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/stop2.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedprogram.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedgame.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedcategory.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/reset_rc.local.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/create_callscript.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedphrase_category.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/import_export_functions.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/adapt_login.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/super_import.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/export_all.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedurl_category.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_port.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_language.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/rotate_logs.pl
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/firefox_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedregexpheader.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedip.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/backup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/work.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/tc_banned
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedmimetype_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/restore.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedSSLsite2.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/get_filterport.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/totalcontrol_lock.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/firehol_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/totalcontrol_load.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/import.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_weightedphrase.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/ban_file.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_user_to_group.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedsitelist.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedurl.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_setting.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/html_logs.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/get-iana.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/test_ports.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedSSLsite.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/deactivate_firehol.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/iptables_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/totalcontrol_unlock.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_net_time.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/restart_the_internet.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/computercontrold.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/cut_the_internet.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/warning.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/netcontrol.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/timewindow.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/other/run_once_at_startup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedregexpurl.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_all.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/restrict_net_to.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedip_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_sq.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedregexpurl_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_fh.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/fun.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/dansguardian_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/service_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/remove_user_from_group.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_downtime.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/tc_status
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/wget_site.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/crontab_add.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/list_all_users.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/get_description.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/check_sitelist.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/cat_from_tar.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/encrypt.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/superbanner.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/choose_categories.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/findbygroup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/forcelogout.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/shred.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/decrypt.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/nonroot/check_time.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_ff.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_dg.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/language_selector.py
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/stop.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/get_status.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/dansguardian_log.pl
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/grep_paragraph.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedurl_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedsite_category.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/keepsafe_until.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/firehol_autostart.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedphrase_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/get_proxyport.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/file_paths.conf
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/import_all.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedmimetype.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/remove.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_program_to_group.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/create_tcs_file.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/start2.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/start.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_weightedphrase_category.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/get_language.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/tc_allowed
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/set_ports.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/adapt_path.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/create_html_log.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/paragraph_search.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/check_tp.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/super_export.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedregexpheader_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/editconf.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/stop_nogui.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/log2html.pl
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/export.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/logout.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/tinyproxy_setup.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedsite_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/autosetports_nogui.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/ban_file_until.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/crontab.locked.template
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/activate_firehol.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/file_paths.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/adapt_mail.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/blanketblock.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/tc_description
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/start_nogui.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedextension_fromfile.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/reset.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/deactivate_html_logs.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedbrowser.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/scripts/add_bannedsite.sh
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/webcontentcontrol_GUI.gambas
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/minimal.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/ucepc.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/exe.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/add.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/compress.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/text.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/denied.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/pics.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/move.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/image-x-generic.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/enable.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/anon.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/update_menus.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/moderate.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/image.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/dialog.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/dg.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/help.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/remove.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/dir.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/limit.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/strict.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/html.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/saved.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/unlock.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/ok.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/lock.png
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/audio.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/script.gif
/usr/share/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol_GUI/icon/disable.png
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/webcontentcontrol.desktop
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/webcontentcontrol
```

Comment: Please post the file /var/lib/dpkg/info/webcontentcontrol.prerm (and please format it as code sample to make it readable).

Comment: @Florian I updated the question with the /var/lib/dpkg/info/webcontentcontrol.prerm formatted as code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webcontentcontrol wasn't letting me install phpmyadmin, but I run

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server mysql-admin libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server mysql-admin libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

in terminal, so now I can use phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

You can post the Portuguese error message or run the command as `LANG=C sudo apt-get remove webcontentcontrol` that will give you the error message in English.

You can also try `sudo dpkg-configure -a` just in case, but knowing the error message will tell us what we need to help.

By the way, if you're embarassed by adult bookmarks, Firefox has a private navigation mode (check under Tools/Ferramentas) where no information is saved by the browser.

Comment: It's LANG=C or LC_ALL=C, not LOCALE=C

Comment: @Florian I updated the question with the full webcontentcontrol removal error message in english.

Comment: Seems like the script depends on `/etc/init.d/firehol` existing. Check if the `firehol` package has that file: `dpkg -L firehol | grep /etc/init.d/firehol` - if a line is returned, than it has, and you should reinstall that package before with `apt-get install --reinstall firehol `. Otherwise, the webcontentcontrol package is broken, please paste the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/webcontentcontrol.prerm` so we can tell you  how to correct it.